# Using different getters in a method

Tags: java, getter

Given the following method

```
public int calcSum(List<MyClass> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .mapToInt(i -> i.getHeight())
                .sum();
}
```

what are my options for using different getters that I can pass in the method's arguments so that I don't have to repeat the same return statement with `getWeight()` for example?

I was thinking of maybe using a different method that would return the getters (if that's possible) but I'm having trouble thinking of a good implementation for that. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't understand your question and there is no getHeight() on String. And going by the rest, I am assuming you want to do something like that: `calcSum(List<String> items, IntFunction toIntFunction) {return items.stream().mapToInt(toIntFunction).sum();}`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Going to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass in a [`ToIntFunction<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) as a parameter:

```
public <T> int calcSum(List<T> items, ToIntFunction<? super T> fn) {
    return items.stream()
                .mapToInt(fn)
                .sum();
}

// Example invocations:
int heightSum = calcSum(items, MyClass::getHeight);
int weightSum = calcSum(items, MyClass::getWeight);
```

---

The `<? super T>` is a a [bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) (specifically a *lower-bounded wildcard*). It just makes the API a little bit more flexible. For example, because of the wildcard, you can call:

```
ToIntFunction<Object> constantValue = a -> 1;
int count = calcSum(items, constantValue);
```

Because `constantValue` accepts any `Object`, it can also accept `MyClass` instances.

Without the bound, you would not be able to pass in a `ToIntFunction<Object>`: for different list element types, you'd need to have separate instances:

```
ToIntFunction<MyClass> constantValueForMyClass = a -> 1;
ToIntFunction<MyOtherClass> constantValueForMyOtherClass = a -> 1;
ToIntFunction<YetAnotherClass> constantValueForYetAnotherClass = a -> 1;
// ...
```

which is just tedious and repetitive.

Comment: Elegant and functional +1

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice! I'm not so experienced with generic methods, could you maybe explain why `<? super T>` is needed here? Why does the function input type need to be a superclass of say `MyClass` (when I'm calling a method from `MyClass`)?

Comment: @SomeAnts added some explanation to the answer.